# Bot Framework Unauthorized when creating a conversation

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm trying to resume a conversation between a bot and a user from a Web Job, and I'm getting an Unauthorized Exception.
I can successfully reply to a conversation in my MessagesController class, but when I try to run the following code in my Web Job, I get the following exception:

```
    private static async Task SendAlertToUser(ChannelAccount botAccount, LipSenseUser user, AlertFlags alert, string extra)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Sending alert to user: {user.Name}");
        var sb = new StringBuilder(GetTextFromAlert(alert));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(extra))
        {
            sb.AppendLine();
            sb.Append(extra);
        }

        var userAccount = new ChannelAccount(user.ChannelId, user.Name);
        var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(user.ChannelUri));

        var message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
        message.From = botAccount;
        message.Recipient = userAccount;

        var conversation = await connector.Conversations.CreateDirectConversationAsync(botAccount, userAccount);

        message.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: conversation.Id);
        message.Locale = "en-Us";
        message.Text = sb.ToString();

        await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)message);
    }
```

And the exception is:

```
Exception:System.UnauthorizedAccessException
Authorization for Microsoft App ID 58c04dd1-1234-5678-9123-456789012345 failed with status code Unauthorized and reason phrase 'Unauthorized'
```

When I inspect the connector's Credentials, I see that everything is correct.  I've set a breakpoint in my MessagesController and inspected the connector's Credentials from there, and everything is identical.

Also, when I look at the IntelliTrace, I see the following messages:

[image: Bot Framework IntelliTrace Errors]

My user.ChannelUri is "https://facebook.botframework.com", which I pulled off of the user when they initialized the conversation.  Is that not the correct Uri?

Is there anything else I need to do to send a message?  My App.config appSettings looks like this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="BotId" value="MyBotName" />
    <add key="MicrosoftAppId" value="58c04dd1-1234-5678-9123-456789012345" />
    <add key="MicrosoftAppPassword" value="5xyadfasdfaweraeFAKEasdfad" />
    <add key="AzureWebJobsStorage" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=BLAH;AccountKey=THIS IS A KEY" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer from Bot Framework Team on a different channel:

> You need to add a call to:
>
> `MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(serviceUrl);`
>
> This is done automatically when you are replying to a message, but for
>   proactive messages from another process you need to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the cross channel post. I generally find that multichannel communication yields the best results!